# Single command to read files from directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a script on myuser@hopbox   which logins to myhost1/myhost2/myhost3 and reads a particular log file for some verification
How can I handle this situation with a single cd command to login to these directories irrespective of whatever server I am on ?

The paths are :

Server Name  Path

myhost1      /export/home/weblogic/jvm11/logs/
myhost2      /export/home/ weblogic /jvm12/logs/
myhost2      /export/home/ weblogic /jvm12/logs/

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias in .bashrc, like

```
alias readlogs="cd /export/home/weblogic/jvm11/logs/; cat logfile1; ..."
```

Then after login, you can execute `readlogs` to do it in one step